# How do I insert a bit of XML into an XDocument using Visual Basic?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, xml, vb.net, sitemap

I'm trying to create a sitemap in an ASP.NET MVC project.

This code in my Node controller...

```vb
Function Sitemap() As ContentResult
    Dim db As New EfrDotOrgEntities
    Dim Nodes = db.Node.ToList
    Dim RequestUrl As Uri = Url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url
    Dim AbsoluteRoot As String = String.Format("{0}://{1}", RequestUrl.Scheme, RequestUrl.Authority)

    Dim map As XDocument = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                           <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
                           </urlset>
    For Each n As Node In Nodes
        map.Add(<url>
                    <loc><%= AbsoluteRoot + Url.RouteUrl("IdOnly", New With {.id = n.Id}) %></loc>
                </url>)
    Next
    Return Content(map.ToString, "text/xml", Encoding.UTF8)
End Function
```

(here's an image because Stack Overflow doesn't color VB code well)

[image: Visual Basic inline XML]

...produces this error:

> This operation would create an
>   incorrectly structured document.

It wouldn't know *where* to add that content.

How do I tell it to insert that bit of XML into the `<urlset>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add it to the top level element in the document (the root):

```
map.Root.Add(...)
```

Comment: I struggled with this for awhile!!

Answer (score 5):

Why not fill it out completely with another xml literal hole?

```
Dim map As XDocument = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                       <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
                           <%= From n In Nodes.Cast(Of Node)() _
                               Select <url>
                                          <loc><%= AbsoluteRoot + Url.RouteUrl("IdOnly", New With {.id = n.Id}) %></loc>
                                      </url> %>
                       </urlset>
```